# Doctrine association mapping between entities in different bundle or relate entities from two different bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, entity-relationship

Region:

```
namespace Acme\RegionBundle\Entity;

class Region
{

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

User:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

class User
{
    private $id;
    private $region_id;
}
```

How to relate entities from different bundle without mentioning fully specified entity path i.e. hard coding dependency.

Is there any better approach ?

Can [Resolve Target Entity Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) be a solution. I couldn't understand how it could be applied here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resolve target entity listener allows you to re-define associations at runtime. It allows you basically to map something like following:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\Namespace\UserInterface")
```

As you can see, mapping an interface as target entity does not make much sense. It becomes really useful when you tell that every `My\Namespace\UserInterface` has to be replaced with a `Other\Namespace\User` reference.